# Why do I have to do ctrl+z twice to break end of file?

Tags: c, windows

Basically I have a struct

```
typedef struct {
const char *nome;
const char *apelido;
int numero;
} Aluno;
```

I want to sort this by `numero`.
For example, Input:

> jonhy_james_123
>
> jack_china_111

Output :

> jack_china_111
>
> jonhy_james_123

I have sucessfully done this, but instead of one CTRL+Z to break end of file, I 
somehow need to do it twice.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct {
const char *nome;
const char *apelido;
int numero;
} Aluno;

Aluno aluno(const char *nome, const char *apelido, int numero)
{
Aluno result;
result.nome = nome;
result.apelido = apelido;
result.numero = numero;
return result;
}

Aluno *Aluno_new (int n)
{
  return (Aluno *) malloc (n * sizeof(Aluno));
}

char *str_dup(const char *s)
{
char *result = (char *) malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
strcpy(result, s);
return result;
}

int aluno_read(Aluno *a)
{
int result = 0;
char nome[50];
char apelido[50];
int numero;
while (scanf("%[^_]_%[^_]_%d\n", nome, apelido, &numero) != EOF) {
  a[result++] = aluno(str_dup(nome), str_dup(apelido), numero);
}

return result;
}

void aluno_write(Aluno *a, int n)
{
printf("%s_%s_%d\n", a[0].nome, a[0].apelido, a[0].numero);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%s_%s_%d\n", a[i].nome, a[i].apelido, a[i].numero);
  }
}


int qsort_cmp_numero(Aluno *x,  Aluno *y)
{
return (x->numero - y->numero);
}

int cmp_B(Aluno *x, Aluno *y)
{
  int result = qsort_cmp_numero(x,y);
  return result;
}


int cmp_final2(const void *p, const void *q)
{
return cmp_B((Aluno *) p, (Aluno *) q);
}

void test_sort()
{
  Aluno *aluno = Aluno_new(100001);
  int n_aluno = aluno_read(aluno);
  qsort(aluno, n_aluno, sizeof(Aluno), cmp_final2);
  aluno_write(aluno, n_aluno);
}

int main()
{
  test_sort();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me guess, you pressed `Ctrl-Z` the first time on a non-empty line? You have to do it on an empty line for it to be sent from the console to your program.

Comment: Because Windows handling is faulty? Usually the sequence is Enter, Ctrl-Z, Enter but it does not always work cleanly. In the past I spent some time investigating this issue: inconclusive.

Comment: I have done ENTER + CTRL+Z, and ctrl+z definitely on an empty line

Comment: What platform are you talking about? Why Ctrl-Z?

Comment: Windows. EOF because I read from stdin for as long as ctrl + z is not pressed.

Comment: Ctrl-Z doesn't have to be on an empty line (unlike Ctrl-D in unix), which is why Enter must follow (though not necessarily immediately).

Comment: @ikegami that is incorrect.

Comment: @Weather Vane, [Test](https://pastebin.com/vZuVUSYn) before contradicting.

Comment: @ikegami I did, I have, many times. In Windows console the `Ctrl-Z` must follow a newline for input to a C program, but thank you for the input. Your example doesn't involve a C program.

Comment: @ikegami and thank you for withdrawing your "don't be a jerk" comment.

Comment: It wasn't constructive, like you original comment.

Comment: @ikegami seeing as yours was no better, I suggest you delete your comments first.

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: Because your example about the behaviour of `Ctrl-Z` had nothing to do with a C program, but mine, after many tests, has. Despite your rep, you are mistaken in your first comment. In Windows C program, `Ctrl-Z` must be preceded and followed by newline. Have you tested that?

Comment: I must say I agree with weather vane.

Comment: You need to clairify whether you're talking about the Windows C runtime (e.g. `scanf`, `fread`, `_read`, etc) or the Windows API (e.g. `ReadFile`, `ReadConsole`). Almost all Ctrl+Z behavior is implemented by the CRT. The only Windows file API that implements Ctrl+Z is `ReadFile` (but not `ReadConsole`), and only when reading from the console in cooked mode (i.e. `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT`), in which case it returns 0 bytes read (i.e. EOF) for any line that begins with Ctrl+Z. Obviously in cooked mode it reads up to a newline, but Ctrl+Z does not have to be followed immediately by a newline.

Answer (score 1):

While behavior of `Ctrl-Z` in Windows has some peculiarities, this is secondary at the moment.

The primary problem is that you placed an `\n` character at the end of your `scanf` format. By doing so you asked `scanf` to wait for non-empty input after the "primary" portion of the input is complete.

This by itself will easily result "strange" behaviors of your `scanf`, like "ignoring" `Enter` key and such.

What is that `\n` doing there? Why did you include it in your format string?

Comment: Still doesnt work...
I make \n to read in the next line the new input

Comment: @James Fernandez: `\n` in `scanf` does not "read in the next line the new input". It has special and completely different meaning. It means "keep reading until you find a non-whitespace character".